# Wordpress get category link

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to ask on how to get the link of each category that have related post on it. I only got some code that will only display parent category. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

`<?php`

`$categories = get_categories();`

```
foreach ($categories as $cat){
   if($cat->parent < 1){
      echo $cat->cat_name ;
   }
}
```

`?>`

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sounds like you may want [get_category_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) - something like:

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url($category_link) . '" title="' . esc_attr($cat->name) . '">' . esc_html($cat->name) . '</a>';
}
```

should print out the links to the categories for you.

Comment: `get_category_link` uses `get_term_link` which applies the `category_link` filter for terms of type `category`. The filter has been deprecated since 2.5.0 (2008-03-29) and WP throws a warning for this. Anyone aware of a way to get a category link without a warning?

Answer (score 3):

According to [`Function Reference/get category link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

```
<?php get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>
```

Example:

```
<?php
// Get the ID of a given category
$category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

// Get the URL of this category
$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>
```