# Get category URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to fetch the category URL for selected categories, however - the query fetches the category correctly, but will not display the URL.

The code I am using is:

```
<?php
    $categories =  get_categories('child_of=38&hide_empty=0');
    $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
    foreach ($categories as $category) :
?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $category->name; ?>
        </a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: you can use <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($category->cat_ID); ?>">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the categories to `$categories` but are using `$cat->cat_ID` for getting the link. Is that a typo or where does `$cat` come from?

Disclaimer: I don't do Wordpress, but the developer resources state that you need to pass a category ID to the get_category_link() function. So I would say what you need to do might be:

```
<?php
    $categories =  get_categories('child_of=38&hide_empty=0');
    foreach ($categories as $category) :
    $category_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $category->name; ?>
        </a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But don't take my word for it ;-)

**Update:** Yes, I just looked further into it and there is actually an answer to this on Stack Overflow already: [Wordpress get category link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816552/wordpress-get-category-link)