# How can I get my thumbnail image to use the category URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a Wordpress slider and change the link on the thumbnail to the category URL instead of the permalink (while still pulling the thumbnail from the post). I started with a slider that used a permalink and the post thumbnail like so:

```
    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="listing-link">
            <?php
            if ( true == $thumbnail ) {
                // if the post has a feature image, show it.
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail( $thumbsize );
                // else if the post has a mime type that starts with "image/" then show the image directly.
                } elseif ( 'image/' == substr( $post->post_mime_type, 0, 6 ) ) {
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $thumbsize );
                }
            }
            ?>
            <div class="title">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Using Wordpress Codex and tips from [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816552/wordpress-get-category-link), I've gotten as far as to change the title beneath the thumbnail correctly, but I can't seem to find the correct combination on the `<a href=""` piece to call the thumbnail's category URL. Is there a way to correctly do this? Here's where I'm at at this point:

```
    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <a href="<?php $categories = get_categories(); foreach ($categories as $cat) { $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); } echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" class="home-category-link">
            <?php
            if ( true == $thumbnail ) {
                // if the post has a feature image, show it.
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail( $thumbsize );
                // else if the post has a mime type that starts with "image/" then show the image directly.
                } elseif ( 'image/' == substr( $post->post_mime_type, 0, 6 ) ) {
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $thumbsize );
                }
            }
            ?>
            <div class="title">
                <?php the_category(); ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

This is the closest I've gotten, but the URL is now pulling a category URL unrelated to the post. Not sure what I'm missing but any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I can't understand if you want category's image or post's image? Can you specify?

Comment: I would be fine with either the category's image or the post's image. The post's image is pulling in currently, but I want it to link to category URL.